# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException using Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, derby

I'm trying to initialize a derby database on startup using Spring jpa.
I have a couple of basic entities. Relevant code follows:

**PersistenceConfiguration class**

```
package org.afsilva.etimer.persistence;

import java.io.File;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("org.afsilva.etimer.persistence")
@PropertySource("org/afsilva/etimer/persistence/application.properties")
public class PersistenceConfiguration {

    private static final String DRIVER_CLASS_NAME = "org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver";
    private static final String DATA_SOURCE_DRIVER_URL = "jdbc:derby:eTimer;create=true";
    private static final String DATA_SOURCE_USER = null;
    private static final String DATA_SOURCE_PASSWORD = null;

    @Bean("entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    
        System.setProperty("derby.system.home", System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separatorChar + "eTimer");
    
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("org.afsilva.etimer.persistence");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("system");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(systemDataSource());

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.DERBY);
        adapter.setShowSql(true);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    DataSource systemDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DRIVER_CLASS_NAME);
        dataSource.setUrl(DATA_SOURCE_DRIVER_URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(DATA_SOURCE_USER);
        dataSource.setPassword(DATA_SOURCE_PASSWORD);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager systemTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
     
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory((entityManagerFactory().getObject()));

        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>e-timer-persistence</artifactId>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.afsilva.etimer</groupId>
        <artifactId>e-timer</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <derby.version>10.15.2.0</derby.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.6.12.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-instrument -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.derby/derby -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>${derby.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.derby/derbytools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbytools</artifactId>
            <version>${derby.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.afsilva.etimer</groupId>
            <artifactId>e-timer-model</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**parent pom**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.afsilva.etimer</groupId>
    <artifactId>e-timer</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        
        <spring-data.version>2.7.3</spring-data.version>
        <spring.version>5.3.23</spring.version>
        <log4j.version>2.18.0</log4j.version>
    </properties>
    
    <modules>
        <module>e-timer-model</module>
        <module>e-timer-persistence</module>
        <module>e-timer-service</module>
        <module>e-timer-standalone</module>
    </modules>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**module-info**

```
module org.afsilva.etimer.persistence {
    requires java.persistence;
    requires spring.data.commons;
    requires spring.context;
    requires transitive org.afsilva.etimer.model;
    requires spring.data.jpa;
    requires spring.orm;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires java.sql;
    requires spring.jdbc;
    requires spring.core;
    requires spring.tx;
    requires spring.instrument;
    
    exports org.afsilva.etimer.persistence.task;
    exports org.afsilva.etimer.persistence;
    
    opens org.afsilva.etimer.persistence.task;
    opens org.afsilva.etimer.persistence.project;
    opens org.afsilva.etimer.persistence.workentry;
    opens org.afsilva.etimer.persistence;
}
```

Spring application context is being initialized like this

```
appCtx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ServiceConfig.class);
```

ServiceConfig class

```
package org.afsilva.etimer.service;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.afsilva.etimer")
public class ServiceConfig {

}
```

when I try to run the application I get

```
13:21:39.466 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8797)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3881)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2607)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:316)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1854)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/instrument/IllegalClassFormatException
    at spring.data.jpa@2.7.3/org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.getConfigurationInspectionClassLoader(JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.java:239)
    at spring.data.commons@2.7.3/org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:97)
    at spring.data.commons@2.7.3/org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:159)
    at spring.data.commons@2.7.3/org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:106)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:395)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:157)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.afsilva.etimer.app/org.afsilva.etimer.ApplicationContext.<clinit>(ApplicationContext.java:12)
    at org.afsilva.etimer.app/org.afsilva.etimer.task.TaskListDialog.initializeTaskList(TaskListDialog.java:62)
    at org.afsilva.etimer.app/org.afsilva.etimer.task.TaskListDialog.<init>(TaskListDialog.java:53)
    at org.afsilva.etimer.app/org.afsilva.etimer.myday.MyDayPane.listTasks(MyDayPane.java:39)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 77 more
```

This is a javafx application, I suppose it has no influence on this issue.

Please help

=== Edit ===

There is a strange behavior here. If I debug the application and go step by step through the initialization code the error does not occur. I wonder if this is some kind of race condition.. Even then I have another issue, which is a query to the database says that the table does not exist, so it seems that "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update" is not working.. :(

Comment: Actually the not creating database tables was pretty simple, just turning "setGenerateDdl" to true.. The only problem now is the racing condition. I wonder if I have any way of triggering database creation/update at startup instead of waiting for first database query...

Answer (score 0):

Check which version of Java you are using. IllegalClassFormatException generally means that you are using jar files which require a *newer* version of Java than the version you are running.

In your pom.xml, it appears you are running Derby 10.15. There are 3 different releases of Derby available right now:

- Derby 10.14 requires Java 8+
- Derby 10.15 requires Java 9+
- Derby 10.16 requires Java 17+

So I'm guessing you're running Java 8. In that case, you can either

- switch to Derby 10.14,
- or, upgrade to Java 9 or higher.

Comment: Hi Bryan, thanks for your response. I'm using java 11 to compile as you can see by the parent pom. To execute I tried java 11 and java 18. This seems to be happening during the instrumentation, so you might be right pointing out dependencies and java version compatibility issue. But it's not a low java version for sure..
Thanks again