# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException on multi module Spring jpa project

Tags: java, maven, spring-data-jpa, java-module

I started with a simple project using spring jpa and a simple maven class just to test this basic behavior. Everything worked fine. My next step was to divide this single project into two projects in order to have a persistence project responsible for data access and another one to be enriched with business logic. This is where everything breaks. The proof that this is related to java modules is that If I delete module-info.java on both projects everything works fine.
If I simply run the application I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/instrument/IllegalClassFormatException
    at spring.data.jpa@2.7.3/org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.getConfigurationInspectionClassLoader(JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.java:239)
    at spring.data.commons@2.7.3/org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:97)
    at spring.data.commons@2.7.3/org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:159)
    at spring.data.commons@2.7.3/org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:106)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:395)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:157)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
    at spring.context@5.3.23/org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:93)
    at test/org.test.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 17 more
```

If I debug it, it starts complaining about missing classes (Derby, hibernate, etc).
All this leads me to believe that the problem is on java module declaration, but I don't know how can I solve this..

This is my file structure:

```
- test
-- src.main.java
--- org.test
---- Config.java
---- Main.java
--- module-info.java
--- src.main.resources
---- org/test/application.properties
-- pom.xml
```

```
- test-persistence
-- src.main.java
--- org.test.persistence
---- CustomRepository.java
---- CustomRepositoryImpl.java
---- Entity.java
---- MyRepository.java
---- PersistenceConfiguration.java
--- module-info.java
-- pom.xml
```

And here are the files:

test pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

        <spring.version>5.3.23</spring.version>
        <spring-data.version>2.7.3</spring-data.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-persistence</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-instrument -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.23</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

test module-info:

```
module test {

    requires testPersistence;

    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires spring.core;
    requires spring.instrument;
    opens org.test;
}
```

Config.java:

```
package org.test;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.test.persistence.PersistenceConfiguration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.test")
@Import(PersistenceConfiguration.class)
public class Config {

}
```

Main.java

```
package org.test;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.test.persistence.Entity;
import org.test.persistence.MyRepository;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Running java " + Runtime.version().feature());

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext appCtx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
        MyRepository repo = appCtx.getBean(MyRepository.class);
        List<Entity> result = repo.findOrderedByLastUsedLimitedTo(2);
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:derby:eTimer;create=true
```

test-persistence pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-persistence</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

        <spring.version>5.3.23</spring.version>
        <spring-data.version>2.7.3</spring-data.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-instrument -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

test-persistence module-info.java:

```
module testPersistence {
    
    requires java.persistence;
    requires java.sql;
    requires spring.data.commons;
    requires spring.data.jpa;
    requires spring.orm;
    requires spring.jdbc;
    requires spring.tx;
    requires spring.context;

    opens org.test.persistence;

    exports org.test.persistence to test;
}
```

CustomRepository.java:

```
package org.test.persistence;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CustomRepository {

    List<Entity> findOrderedByDescriptionLimitedTo(int maxItems);
}
```

CustomRepositoryImpl.java:

```
package org.test.persistence;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

public class CustomRepositoryImpl implements CustomRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<Entity> findOrderedByDescriptionLimitedTo(int limit) {
        return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Entity p ORDER BY p.description", Entity.class)
                .setMaxResults(limit).getResultList();
    }
}
```

Entity.java:

```
package org.test.persistence;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "Entity")
public class Entity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String description;

    public Entity() {
        super();
    }

    public Entity(Long id, String description) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

MyRepository.java:

```
package org.test.persistence;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long>, CustomRepository {

    Entity save(Entity task);
}
```

PersistenceConfiguration.java:

```
package org.test.persistence;

import java.io.File;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("org.test.persistence")
@PropertySource("org/test/application.properties")
public class PersistenceConfiguration {

    private static final String DRIVER_CLASS_NAME = "org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver";
    private static final String DATA_SOURCE_DRIVER_URL = "jdbc:derby:test;create=true";
    private static final String DATA_SOURCE_USER = null;
    private static final String DATA_SOURCE_PASSWORD = null;

    @Bean("entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        
        System.setProperty("derby.system.home", System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separatorChar + "test");
        
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("org.test");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("system");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(systemDataSource());

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.DERBY);
        adapter.setShowSql(true);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    DataSource systemDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DRIVER_CLASS_NAME);
        dataSource.setUrl(DATA_SOURCE_DRIVER_URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(DATA_SOURCE_USER);
        dataSource.setPassword(DATA_SOURCE_PASSWORD);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager systemTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory((entityManagerFactory().getObject()));

        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

help please?

Comment: Seems to be [the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74079553/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-java-lang-instrument-illegalclassformatexcepti) what you addressed weeks ago. It is all about the `ClassNotFoundException` i.e. the class `java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException` could not be found. This class is actually in the module `java.base` which is implicit so I assume you have an issue with a mix of different JDK versions.

Comment: First approach should be to let it run without the Java Module System, i.e. delete the `module-info.java` stuff and not before this works smoothly consider to modularize it.

Comment: Thanks kladderradatsch, That's exactly what I did. I push the modularization forward in time. Now it works. For some reason I can no longer run javafx application directly from eclipse and have to use the maven plugin. :( Now I have a new challenge, how to debug this app :(

Comment: Actually found the solution here https://edencoding.com/runtime-components-error/. I'll keep this path and get back to the modularization later on. This is not really a fix, so not setting this as selected answer.

Comment: You have to build *test-persistence* first via `$>mvn clean install` so this artifact is stored/installed into your local maven repository (~/.m2/repository). Then it can be found by your *test* artifact which depends on *test-persistence*.

Answer (score 0):

I have like the same problem as you and I strongly think that the problem is that one "thing" (probably something in one module) want to have access to another "thing" (also probably something in another module). Because of the module strategy (what is declared by using module-info.java) -*what is an access restriction to have access between the imported modules*- you get the `ClassNotFoundException`.

For this the solution is to give "access" one module to the other module. Actually I didn't found a way to find out what module want to have access to what.

In your case I think something want to have access to `java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException` what means in the `module-info.java` file you need an `opens ... to ...` or `export ... to ...` (or probably only a `requires ...`) within `java.instrument`-module.